# Laravel - asset() function noy working well

Tags: javascript, css, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a problem with my laravel project.

In my link.blade.php file I have:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="{!! asset(css/bootstrap.min.css) !!}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{!! asset(css/theme.css) !!}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{!! asset(css/bootstrap-reset.css) !!}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and when a run my server I got:

```
Use of undefined constant css - assumed 'css' (View: 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/views/partials/links.blade.php) (View: 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/views/partials/links.blade.php) (View: 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/views/partials/links.blade.php) (View: 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/views/partials/links.blade.php)
```

it's looks like the compiler can't get my css/bootstrap.min.css (located in public dir).

When I've removed this css file it's move to the second one and so on (also js files).

Public dir:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9YV5.png)

What I should do, please help!!

Comment: you just forgot `''` so it needs to be `asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your files structure you just need to reference to it directly no need to the `asset()`function

**It would be like this**

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/bootstrap-reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

*****Deu certo comigo retirando a função asset*****

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around strings:

```
<link href="{!! asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') !!}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: No problem. Please accept answer so people can see it's answered

Answer (score 0):

**You Need to Keep css and JS files like this**

[image]

**For More Details** https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravels-5-csslink?page=1